# Resize range based on cell values to create chart

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I have data that im trying to graph and need a way to automatically size the chart range to ensure that no values of zero get graphed. Essentially, if I have a 10 row by 4 column range of data and everything below row 5 id zeros, i want a macro that will select the data in the first 5 rows only to make the chart and leave the other sets of data alone.

Any ideas would be appreciated

EDIT

I tried to set the zero values to N/A so the chart wouldn't plot them but it did. I'm now trying to modify the loop i made so that it will go down the data until it reaches a value of 0, once it does it will select the all the data and fields above it and define that as my chart data:

```
    Dim xlastrow As Integer
    Dim xrow As Integer
    xrow = 15
    Range("b10000").End(xlUp).Select
    xlastrow = ActiveCell.Row
    Range("c10000").End(xlUp).Select


    Do Until Cells(xrow, 2).Value = "0"
      If Cells(xrow, 2).Value <> "0" Then
      Cells(xrow, 2).Select


    End If
    xrow = xrow + 1
    Loop
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.offset(, -1).Select
```

This code works to identify where the last row of non-zero values is and it selects the first cell in the row (the cell with the x-axis description of the value in the future chart). how do i complete the code so that it selects everything on top and to the right and defines that as my chart area?

Comment: This can be done but what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please read the [On Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help pages so we can better assist you.

Comment: I edited my initial post to add the code i tried. I've reached the last row i want to be in my data i just now need to select everything above it and define that range as my chart data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an index of articles that will help you create dynamic charts: [Dynamic Chart Review](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/dynamic-chart-review/).